# NoReverseMatch at /blog/2018/

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Help me please. I don't know this problem...
What's the problem?
Html code image :
[image]

Error page image : 
[image]

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
      -- skip --

      # Example: /2018/nov/
      url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', PostYAV.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),

      -- skip --
]
```

blog/views.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from django.views.generic.dates import --skip--, YearArchiveView, --skip--

-- skip --

class PostYAV(YearArchiveView):
     model = Post
     date_field = 'modify_date'
     make_object_list = True
```

Comment: Please give your code and error output as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying with this url:

```
 url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/$', PostYAV.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),
```

Then call it from Template like this:

```
{% url 'blog:post_year_archive' year|date:'Y' %}
```

And the View should be like this:

```
class PostYAV(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    make_object_list = True

    def get(self, request, year, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.filter(created__year=year)  # assuming created= models.DateField() or similar
```

**But** if you have month as well(as like the image shared with the question, then try like this)

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', PostYAV.as_view(), name='post_year_archive'),
```

**Template**:

```
  {% url 'blog:post_year_archive' year|date:'Y' month|date:'m' %}
```

**View:**

```
class PostYAV(YearArchiveView):
    model = Post
    date_field = 'modify_date'
    make_object_list = True

    def get(self, request, year, month, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.filter(created__year=year, created__month=month)  # assuming created= models.DateField() or similar
```

The error in your question occured because the url regex did not match with arguments passing from template. `%b` is showing localized month and did not match regex `[a-z]{3}`. So instead `%m` will pass the month as a number and we have updated the regex for month to catch the number sent from template.